# wheel is invalid in pip

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

When I try to install something via pip in pycharm, I get the following error. - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08cvi.png)

Anyone have a solution?

I tried install it via cmd but it is the same. When I am trying to update pip, setuptools I am getting the same error.

Comment: Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: First thing that sticks out: The download bar should be full (at 100%). Looks like the download failed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have enough space on your device? Can you try running `pip install selenium --no-cache-dir`?